# My Plotly plots are cut off in my Streamlit app

Tags: plotly, streamlit

I'm plotting some data in Streamlit and the site looks great on my desktop.
However when I view it on my mobile device the right side is cut off.
My code:

```py
fig = go.Figure()
fig.add_trace(go.Scatter(x=[time.strftime('%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S', time.localtime(t)) for t in times], y=[i for i in range(num_times)], mode='lines+markers'))
st.plotly_chart(fig)
```

How can I fix this?

Answer (score 1):

You can force the plot to have the right width on mobile by changing the line

```
st.plotly_chart(fig)
```

to

```
st.plotly_chart(fig, use_container_width=True)
```

.